# Mongodb group by specific field in the collection and also return the count for each

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection in mongodb which stores document like the following

ORDERS collection

```
_id:ObjectId(5f87b9f8f1bfc578dc3d8c9a)
user_id:"5f8465a777b1814c588521e2"
coords:{lat:0,long:0}
price:96
state:"Haryana"
quantity:"1"
timestamp:2020-10-15T02:54:48.104+00:00
status:3
driver_id:"5f7ab962f2bd85066c6f24bd"
monthNumber:9



_id:ObjectId(5f87b9f8f1bfc578dc3d8c9a)
order_id:"200d0019-a4cb-471b-bb70-a22c3056153d"
user_id:"5f8465a777b1814c588521e2"
coords:{lat:0,long:0}
price:96
state:"Haryana"
quantity:"1"
timestamp:2020-10-15T02:54:48.104+00:00
status:3
driver_id:"5f7ab962f2bd85066c6f24bd"
monthNumber:9

_id:ObjectId(5f87b9f8f1bfc578dc3d8c9a)
order_id:"200d0019-a4cb-471b-bb70-a22c3056153d"
user_id:"5f8465a777b1814c588521e2"
coords:{lat:0,long:0}
price:96
state:"Haryana"
quantity:"1"
timestamp:2020-10-15T02:54:48.104+00:00
status:3
driver_id:"5f7ab962f2bd85066c6f24bd"
reviewStatus:2
monthNumber:8
```

Now what i want is that in frontend i want to group the data and show it according to

> "monthNumber"

so that client has idea the how many orders were placed in a particular month (0-Jan... 9-oct)

what i did was i ran a query like

```
let orders = await db
      .collection("orders")
      .aggregate({
        $group:{
          _id:"monthNumber",count:{$sum:1}
        }
      })
```

but it gave error of

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

and also i see in console that aggregation cursor was printed instead of actual info.

Comment: How about `_id:"$monthNumber"` ?

Comment: well i also did await db
      .collection("orders")
      .aggregate([
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$monthNumber",
            count: { $sum: 1 },
          },
        },
      ]) and then it seems to work :)